# Redirect to another page by clicking on a link in modal windows

Tags: window, modal-dialog, socialengine

**I have a modal window that displays a list of my groups that I create, I want by clicking on the name of the group modal window closes and redirects to the group profile is made
here is the link line

echo $this->htmlLink($link, $group->getTitle());

$link is a static link like domaine/group/4
thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript:

```
parent.Smoothbox.close();
```

and then redirect using javascript (with `parent` which means change location property of the parent window).